# How can I change a text label from another file in python tkinter?

Tags: python, file, tkinter, label

I hope you can help me, because I am stuck on this.
I have an application on tkinter, bassically I need that when pressing a button a function from another python file is executed and changes the text of a label.

Let me explain:

My frontend file is called `ODF_principal.py` and my backend file is called `ODF_second.py`, in the backend file I have functions.

I imported `ODF_second.py` as`OFU` on `ODF_principal` to set `command` in button properties like the following:

```
btn_Open = Button(frame_menu, text="Open file", command=OFU.open_file)
```

`btn_Open` belongs to frontend

Well, when I run the function, I need that when a file is opened or not, change the text of a label that belongs to the frontend file.

```
lbl_file = Label(frame_menu)
```

I've tried to import the frontend file into de backend but I've got an error of CIRCULAR IMPORT, so here is the function that I need it to be able to change the text of `lbl_file`

```
opened_file_path=""

def open_file():
global opened_file_path
opened_file_path=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",
            title = "Select files",filetypes = (("TXT files","*.txt"),
            ("All files","*.*")))
if not opened_file_path:
    opened_file_path = ""
**OFR.lbl_file.config(text=opened_file_path)**
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using a lambda function:

```
btn_Open = Button(frame_menu, text="Open file", command= lambda: OFU.open_file(lbl_file))
```

And then

```
def open_file(label):
    global opened_file_path
    opened_file_path=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",
    title = "Select files",filetypes = (("TXT files","*.txt"),
            ("All files","*.*")))
    if not opened_file_path:
        opened_file_path = ""
    label.config(text=opened_file_path)
```

The lambda function allows you to pass a reference to the label to your function in the other file.

Comment: I tried your solution, it works super fine. Thank you for your time, I didn't know about lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by getting `open_file` to return the file path and altering the label in your frontend.

```
def button_press():
    file_open = OFU.open_file
    my_label.configure(text=file_open)

btn_Open = Button(frame_menu, text="Open file", command=button_press)
```

And

```
def open_file():
    opened_file_path=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",
                title = "Select files",filetypes = (("TXT files","*.txt"),
                ("All files","*.*")))
    if not opened_file_path:
        opened_file_path = ""
    return opened_file_path
```

This is an alternative to @Henry's answer that means your backend doesn't have to handle any of the GUI

Comment: Thank you,I tried it but It didn't worked :( as expected

Comment: This solution will work, you just need to implement it correctly (use the correct label name etc)